# Using PHP to output JSON data and getting white screen

Tags: php, json

Here is my PHP codes for JSON data. When I want to open localhost/x/json.php. I'm getting a white screen.

```
<?php

$host = "**";
$user = "**";
$pass = "**";
$db = "**";


$sql = "select * from diziler";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   array_push($response,array("dizi"=>$row[0],"kanal"=>$row[1],"sure"=>$row[2]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: white screen => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and even http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: debug it using error reporting and `echo`s or `var_dump`s in your code.

Comment: It is woking on domain but doesnt work on localhost. What kind of mystery is this?

Comment: Perhaps your database does not allow for remote connections?

Comment: Perhaps there isn't even a database? `mysqli_error()` and PHP error log should hold a clue.

Comment: I fix this. `if ($con->connect_errno || !mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")) {
printf("hata $s\n", $con->connect_error);
} ` I added this. Because my database consist "ç,ö,ğ,ı" character.